# Proving the image of a parallelogram is a parallelogram after a linear transformation.

Tags: linear-algebra, transformation

Let T be an invertible linear transformation from R2 to R2. Let P be a parallelogram in R2 with one vertex at the origin.

Is the image of P a parallelogram? How would I go about finding this out?

I know I need to somehow show more than just the vertices form a parallelogram. Would I need to think about the transformation of the "edge" vectors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $v$ and $w$ two linearly independent vectors. Then the parallelogram $P(v,w)$ with sides $v$ and $w$ is the set of vectors
$$
P(v,w)=\{av+bw\mid (a,b)\in[0,1]^2\}.
$$
Let $T$ be a linear transformation. Then one has clearly 
$$
T(P(v,w))=\{aT(v)+bT(w)\mid (a,b)\in[0,1]^2\}
$$
which immediately shows that
$$
T(P(v,w))=P(T(v),T(w)).
$$

---

This remains true even if the parallelogram does not have a vertex in the origin. In fact if $P$ is any parallelogram, then
$$
P=u+P(v,w)
$$
for some vector $u$. But then
$$
T(P)=T(u)+P(T(v),T(w))
$$
as above

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** linear mappings take lines to lines: $$T({\bf p}+ t {\bf v}) = T{\bf p} + tT{\bf v}.$$
Look at the images of the four sides of your figure by $T$.

Comment: What do you mean the "image of the four sides"? It's an unspecified linear transformation, how can I see that?

Comment: A parallelogram has opposite sides parallel to each other, right? Prove that the images of these sides by a linear mapping are still parallel. The quicker way would be with coordinates.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I'll try that.

Comment: @ivo terek dont we need the invertibility of the transform.

Comment: Absolutely you do. Take $T=0$ as an extreme counterexample.